# Failing to update a Location using the Google My Business API

Tags: google-api, patch, google-my-business-api

For a while now I've been trying to build up a working `PATCH` request for updating a Location through Googles My Business API, but I have yet to make a successful request.

This is what my last attempt of a request looks likes:

```
{
  location": {
    "primaryPhone": "1-800-TEST"
  },
  "languageCode": "en",
  "fieldMask": "primaryPhone",
  "validateOnly": true
}
```

When I omit something like the `fieldMask` I get an error saying that `address.country` is not set, but with it present I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Not very informative :P

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Does anyone have a working sample request? (preferably one that updates opening hours) :)

Comment: Kind of hard to help with out seeing your code but.   Try and do a locations.get   that will return a location body make your changes to that and patch it back.   I think you need to set all the fields you cant pick and chose.

Comment: From what I understand (https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v2/accounts.locations/patch#request-body) I should be able to only submit the fields I need to update if I specify which fields using the `fieldMask` property: 

`The specific fields to update. If no mask is specified, then this is treated as a full update and all fields are set to the values passed in, which may include unsetting empty fields in the request.`

`A comma-separated list of fully qualified names of fields. Example: "user.displayName,photo".`

Comment: The code also isn't very interesting as for example the `GET` request is working fine - I'm almost certain that there's something wrong with the body of the request, but I haven't been able to figure out what yet :)

Comment: That's the theory I have never gotten it to work by only sending a couple of fields however sending everything works.

Comment: Then that could be problem its not a HTTP Get request its a HTTP Patch request.

Comment: No I mean the GET requests work - but there's something wrong with the body of the PATCH request :)

Answer (score -1):

I wound up here while looking for an example before making it work.  So, better late than never, here is a working answer.

There is a distinction between fields that describe how the request should be processed, and the data that goes into the location.  The former go after a ? in the URL.  The latter goes into the body.

So you should issue a:

```
PATCH https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v3/accounts/$accountId/locations/$locationId?languageCode=en&fieldMask=primaryPhone&validateOnly=true
```

with a body of:

```
{"primaryPhone":  "1-800-TEST"}
```

Assuming that you have a valid `Authorization` header, this should work.